# How to validate whether an ip in the white list

Tags: java, ip, wildcard

I have a IP white list , it's a string array like {"192.168.1.1" ,"172.8.9.9", "198.2.3.*", "89.90.9.9-78"}, seen from this array we know that it contains ip with wildcard "*", and ip between 89.90.9.9  to  89.90.9.78 that expressed by "89.90.9.9-78".

The question is  how can I judge an ip is in this array, can i use the regular expression?

I'm using java.

code snippet
I write code like this     `

```
String[] ipWhiteList = {"192.168.1.1" ,"172.8.9.9", "198.2.3.", "89.90.9.9-78"};

    List<String> ipWithoutWildcard = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> ipWithWildcard = new ArrayList<String>();
    private void analyzeIPWhiteList(String[] ipWhiteList){
        for (String ip : ipWhiteList) {if(ip.endsWith("*")){
 ipWithWildcard.add(ip.substring(0,ip.lastIndexOf(".")));
                break;
            }
            if(ip.contains("-")){
                String partionOfIP = ip.substring(0,ip.lastIndexOf("-"));
                int ipBegin = Integer.parseInt(ip.substring(ip.lastIndexOf(".")+1,ip.lastIndexOf("-")));
                int ipEnd = Integer.parseInt(ip.substring(ip.lastIndexOf("-")+1));
                for (int index=ipBegin; index<=ipEnd; index++) {
                    ipWithoutWildcard.add(partionOfIP+"."+ index);
                }
                break;
            }
            ipWithoutWildcard.add(ip);
        }
    }

    private boolean isExist(String ip,List<String> ipWithoutWildcard,List<String> ipWithWildcard){
        //compare the ip in  ipWithoutWildcard and ipWithWildcard
        return false;
    }
```

`

Comment: Yes, you can use regex.

Comment: Better question: what have you tried?

Comment: @Maroun Maroun, how can i implement this using regex, I'll write a long list for that, like 192.168.1.1|172.8.9.9|198.2.3.\d  ....

Comment: @AntonH  I've wrote code snippet, like to compare the ip with ip in this white list , but you know it does not have the versatility

Comment: Share the code and tell us , where actually you got stucked.